# Leverage browser caching on Blogger

Tags: caching, browser-cache, blogger

Blogger doesn't have a `.htaccess` file. How can I cache on Blogger?

Answer (score 1):

You must need to know if the Blogger had an automatically controlled platform, for features experts can only detect and use these features. 
Like you, I have analysed page speed and found one of the images in your page needs a leveraged browser cache.

Edit the post and check the image size and do like the example below.

If your post / page has one image of
 Size 100 KB 300x300, but on the post you have inserted the image as extra large or too small
instead of the original size.

Now just click on the image in edit post and set it to the original size to update the post.

Now again analyse the page speed you will see the image has vanished and the page speed will improve. You can do this will for every kind of content; just think deeply and discover new ways.

Comment: Modern English doesn't capitalize (almost) every word like that.  It makes it quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this simple code on blogger template, after head
copy this code,

```
<include expiration='7d' path='*.css'/>
<include expiration='7d' path='*.js'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='*.gif'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='*.jpeg'/>    
<include expiration='3d' path='*.jpg'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='*.png'/>
```